# Can't render some variables in twig template

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twig

I've written my application using ZF2.
I have 2 modules: mail and file.
All vars from mail module are rendered. Can't render object file.
When I do `{{ dump(mail.file) }}` it returns `NULL`. But if I do `{{ dump() }}` the file object does exist:

```
array (size=2)
  'mail' => 
    object(Mail\Entity\Incoming)[453]
      protected 'id' => int 8
      protected 'inNumber' => int 1
      protected 'inDate' => int 1320948000
      protected 'outNumber' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected 'outDate' => int 1320948000
      protected 'sheetsNumber' => int 1
      protected 'teaser' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'file' => 
        object(File\Entity\File)[455]
          protected 'id' => int 5
          protected 'origName' => string 'eRa33cHgofw.jpg' (length=15)
          protected 'curName' => string 'eRa33cHgofw.jpg' (length=15)
          protected 'size' => int 284192
          protected 'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          protected 'uploaded' => int 1385736080
      protected 'sender' => 
        object(Mail\Entity\Sender)[457]
          protected 'id' => int 1
          protected 'name' => string 'ООО Ромашка' (length=21)
      protected 'type' => 
        object(Mail\Entity\Type)[459]
          protected 'id' => int 1
          protected 'name' => string 'Информация' (length=20)
      protected 'created' => int 1385736080
  'namespace' => string 'FileEntityFile' (length=14)
```

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` property in the `Mail\Entity\Incoming` class is `protected` hence it is only accessible from within the class itself or any children of the `Mail\Entity\Incoming` class. This why twig can't access that property.

Either make the property `public` or create an accessor function within the `Mail\Entity\Incoming` class.

Comment: Thanks, with property public accessed. How I can create accessor function, is some example?